# How to do a Beacon paring bluetooth

Tags: beacon

Hi Would like to do bluetooth pairing request with the ALteBeacon library, in order to establish communication between two devices because I did a virtual beacon.  Is it Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android Beacon Library is designed for Bluetooth LE Beacon detection, ranging and monitoring.  It is not designed for Bluetooth LE GATT communications.  For that purpose, please use the built-in Android APIs.  See the Connect to a GATT Server section [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le).

Comment: Thank you very much for your support and adviser, I will see the link.

Paulo